# setting an image as background

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi Guys Im using this class to put a responsive image as a background for a div, it works well and it is responsive . the only issue I have is that the image is not shown completely, I mean it is a large image, it is centered and everything is correct except that I can't see the top and the bottom of the image, what can I add to see this large image fully and keep the responsive behavior?

```
.bg {
  background-image:url("image local url");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Try `background-size: contain`

Comment: It all depends on your html and other css. What are the image and object dimensions? How is `.hg` used and what other classes does the element have?

Comment: @OskarLaska okay with contain I can see the top upon scrolling down only, and the right and left are not filling the div anymore

Comment: @sisimh Try to imagine this. How do you want the image to fill container both dimmensions? It would shrink and wouldn't look too nice (`background-size: 100% 100%`). You can try other [options of background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: @sisimh unless the window is the exact apsect ratio of the image, you will always get some sort of clipping.  If it is the top and bottom of the background image that is most important, then resize it so that it is wider and therefore it is more likely to keep the top and bottom on the screen and clip the sides

Comment: thanks @Pete that was the missing info, so that means I should fix the dimensions of the image to fit the desktop and it will do the responsive part by clipping top, bottom, right and left and yet still be centered. right?

Comment: @Pete but each screen is different than the other (desktop) how can I know how much wide to make it wider?

Answer (score 0):

You must put the actual img tag with the correct image and hide it with css. Something like this:

```
img {
   width: 100%;
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

With this method, the actual img will resize the container to the proper content so that it always fits the image and you will get the quality of the background image. Let me know if this works

Comment: So why not just use the image if you are going to put it in the div? why use it, hide it and then make it a background?

Comment: So that you can properly add content ontop of the image without using hacks like z-index. In addition, this is a very good workaround for slider galleries, since the images customers provide are usually with wrong size (dimentions) and this workaround combined with max-height and min-height for the container, will make the slider gallery responsive. That's a little off topic, but this is a generally good to know 'hack'.

Comment: again, why not just use the image as you are going to have to place the content on top of the invisible image anyway and adding 1 z-index (which is not a hack - your invisible image is a hack) is not the end of the world if you know how to use z-index's properly